# VGG16 transfer learning

Tags: deep-learning

When I try to implement transfer learning to train my ConvNet model, there's a snippet of code that I don't understand in this Keras blog (goo.gl/N60H13). In total, VGG16 has 21 layers, but in order to freeze all the other layers than the final FC, the number of the layers that I need to freeze would be 20. Does anyone understand why the blog made it to be 24 ([:25])?

The code:

```
for layer in model.layers[:25]:
    layer.trainable = False
```

Answer (score 1):

***layer.trainable = False*** is used for Transfer Learning concept inside Machine learning. In order to do that, we freeze the 24 layers and keep the output layer unfreezed, so we can train our own networks over it.

Answering simply, the last layer is the output layer. We don't want to freeze that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has something to do with the Kera's framework.

From this [gist](https://gist.github.com/baraldilorenzo/07d7802847aaad0a35d3), we know that `VGG16 model for Keras has been obtained by directly converting the Caffe model.` So, it originally counts with the `zero-padding layers` as well. Double checked with the [revision history](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/7eb39b44eb9e16e59632d25fb3119975/revisions), it indeed contains those `zero-padding layers`.

For current version of [VGG16](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/vgg16.py) from Kera's, maybe it should be

```
for layer in model.layers[:15]:
    layer.trainable = False
```